# Insert into several tables at once with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Not that new to SQL development anymore, but new to EF.

I have a few tables that are related. I was wondering if EF can insert multiple rows in the table that generates the IDENTITY key then the table(s) that hold related data.

About to start doing some learning on EF, but to know this is possible would motivate me more (keep my up longer at night while learning the subject).

If its possible it is something I could really use.

Comment: "...generates the IDENTITY key then the table(s) that hold related data."  Can you put more light on it? And yes entity framework can insert multiple rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may insert both parent and child data (each of which are new) at the same time when using Entity Framework. You can take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/05/entity-framework-inserting-objects-with.html) for a very basic example of how to do so.